RegExr for validating proper URL
I am using the following regular expression to validate URLs. However, it fails to validate URLs like "https://stackoverflow[.]onion"
Here is the regular expression:
/^$|^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www\.)?[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+(\.[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+)+((\/)[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+)*(\/[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+\?[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+=[^&=]+(&[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+=[^&=]+)*)?$/im

I want to exclude the square brackets.

It's unclear what your question is. The regular expression you provided does validate https://stackoverflow.onion when the square brackets are removed. The URL as shown in your question is invalid because the square brackets would need to be URL-encoded first prior to transmission.

@PeterJ.Mello
"My RegExr correctly validates 'https://stackoverflow.onion,' but it also validates 'https://stackoverflow[.]onion,' which I want to exclude."

So remove all \[\] in your pattern.

@WiktorStribiżew still it show "https://stackoverflow[.]onion" is valid.
could you provide me with the RegExr.

Do you really need a regular expression? Narek's answer using the URL() constructor works fine, as it throws an exception with an invalid URL (containing these brackets). By the way, your question already exists: what is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL

No, you just did not do it properly. Also, the - after $ must be escaped if you mean to match a literal -. See https://regex101.com/r/UTHgPj/1

@WiktorStribiżew, thanks it works.

Something like this might work.
^(?:(?:ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(?:[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+(\[\.\]|\.){1}[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+)*(?:\/[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]*)*(?:\?[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+=[^&=]+(?:&[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+=[^&=]+)*)?(?:#[\w$-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~\[\]<>#%"]+)?$

You can use URL constructor to validate the URLs:
function isValidUrl(url) {
    try {
        new URL(url);
        return true;
    } catch (_) {
        return false;
    }
}


It passes for "https://stackoverflow[.]onion" which i don't want.

Oh,my bad. I thought you want that too :)
Try this one:
^$|^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(www\.)?([a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~<>#%"]+)+((\/)[a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~<>#%"]+)*(\/[a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~<>#%"]+\?[a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~<>#%"]+=[^&=]+(&[a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),#%{}|\\^~<>#%"]+=[^&=]+)*)?$
